# My coworker and I got into the same post graduate program and we both plan on accepting. Can we be reprimanded?

Tags: resignation, ethics

My coworker and I both got into the same postgraduate program and both intend to leave the company we are at.  We are close friends and are both interested in a career in a similar field.  We both knew we were applying, but our decisions were separate. Should I be concerned about legal repercussions if I go through with my plan to leave for the program?

There is a statement in my contract that while at the company I cannot directly or indirectly attempt a fellow employee to terminate their employment.

Comment: Is there some contract that restricts your leaving?

Comment: What makes you think there are potential legal repercussions?

Comment: Suggestion: Do tell the company your intent sooner than later. They may offer to put you on leave rather than forcing you to quit, or suggest that you might continue working for them part-time. (Actually, you should have talked to them about your educational plans before applying; some companies have educational benefits that will help pay tuition, or let you stay on the company medical plan. I'm still kicking myself for not having taken more advantage of that during my career.)

Answer (score 13):

> We both knew we were applying but our decisions were separate

As both of you do not incite the other to join the new company, and both of you apply for new jobs at new companies independently, everything should be fine. You should have nothing to worry about.

---

> There is a statement in my contract that while at the company I cannot directly or indirectly attempt a fellow employee to terminate their employment.

If the current company files a complaint about your alleged violation of this particular policy, they will have to prove that by showing some paper trails indicating that you two communicate with each other and ask the other to quit the current company for a new job elsewhere.

Again, it does not look like you violate their policy in this case.

Answer (score 3):

> Should I be concerned about legal repercussions if I go through with my plan to leave for the program?

No.

Your company may not be happy about it, but as long as you didn't attempt to coerce your coworker into leaving, you are fine.

Comment: What does "coerce" mean in this context? Can't i talk to my coworker in a manner like "F*ck this shit company, lets apply there and see if we get anywhere". Feels like private talk that noone can prevent me from doing?